# Inconsistent handling property values in JanusGraph

Tags: janusgraph, gremlin-server

Getting some problem while playing with JanusGraph. I am new in JanusGraph recently I have installed and followed the documentation for add vertex with its properties and few more but when I am trying to insert a property of float digit and set the key as `"abc"` and value would be `9.5f` in this case I got an error but in the same query when I change the key to `"a"` or something else it works fine.

Example with key `abc`

`g.addV("T22").property("abc", 9.5f)`

Error

`Value [9.5] is not an instance of the expected data type for property key [abc] and cannot be converted. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, found: class java.lang.Float`

Example with key `a`

`g.addV("T22").property("a", 9.5f)` working fine

`g.V(163848208).valueMap()
{a=[10.5]}`

**updated**

[image]

Got the same error again the error occurred only with 2 properties keys

1. `abc`
2. `Mailing_Code`

Comment: Did you create a schema before you executed those traversals? It looks like the `abc` property is already defined as an `Integer`. Also did you change the value of `schema.default` in your configuration?

Comment: I recreated the server and tested the same code with key `abc` and its working the same problem occurred with `Mailing_Code` now this also fixed but I didn't change anything and not set any property I just followed the documentation **http://docs.janusgraph.org/0.1.0/getting-started.html**

Comment: how do I create the schema

Comment: I have tested same keys with different property value but didn't get any error the problem has happened only with this keys.

Answer (score 3):

By default, JanusGraph uses an [automatic schema maker](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/schema.html#_automatic_schema_maker). When a new property key is used, it will define a property key with its data type based on the value. In your scenario, it sounds like the first usage of `abc` used `Integer` rather than `Float`. Here's an example recreating your scenario:

```
gremlin> JanusGraph.version()
==>0.2.0
gremlin> graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('inmemory')
==>standardjanusgraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[standardjanusgraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]], standard]
gremlin> g.addV("T22").property("abc", 9).iterate()
gremlin> g.tx().commit()
==>null
gremlin> g.addV("T22").property("abc", 9.5f).iterate()
Value [9.5] is not an instance of the expected data type for property key [abc] and cannot be converted. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, found: class java.lang.Float
```

After a property key is defined, its data type cannot be changed. As described in the docs:

> It is strongly encouraged to explicitly define all schema elements and to disable automatic schema creation by setting `schema.default=none` in the JanusGraph graph configuration.

Doing so will give you better control over the schema that is created. Here's an example on how to do that:

```
gremlin> graph = JanusGraphFactory.build().
......1>     set('storage.backend', 'inmemory').
......2>     set('schema.default', 'none').
......3>     open()
==>standardjanusgraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> mgmt = graph.openManagement()
==>org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@46aa712c
gremlin> mgmt.makeVertexLabel('T22').make()
==>T22
gremlin> mgmt.makePropertyKey('abc').dataType(Float.class).make()
==>abc
gremlin> mgmt.commit()
==>null
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[standardjanusgraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('T22').property('abc', 9).iterate()
gremlin> g.tx().commit()
==>null
gremlin> g.addV('T22').property('abc', 9.5f).iterate()
gremlin> g.tx().commit()
==>null
gremlin> g.V().values('abc').map{ [ it.get(), it.get().getClass().getName() ] }
11:29:34 WARN  org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes
==>[9.5,java.lang.Float]
==>[9.0,java.lang.Float]
```

Here is a link to the [documentation](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/schema.html) on JanusGraph schema which has more information.